# See my own HeaderDoc in Xcode

Tags: xcode4, headerdoc

I write a lot of C#, and in Visual Studio I can see my own documentation when autocomplete appears to describe the function and its parameters. Is this same functionality available in Xcode using my HeaderDoc descriptions?

If it helps the relevance of any answers, I am using Xcode 4.

Answer (score 1):

Asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751278/how-do-you-populate-the-xcode-4-optionclick-popover).

Answer (score 1):

[Appledoc](http://www.gentlebytes.com/home/appledocapp/) generates documentation sets as necessary to populate autocomplete, described in the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751278/how-do-you-populate-the-xcode-4-optionclick-popover) by [Joshua Nozzi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103685/see-my-own-headerdoc-in-xcode/6104951#6104951). I'm not sure if HeaderDoc generates these also.

Comment: Not good to put links in answer, links sometimes expire, which is the case with your appledoc link.