# Quick Help for user defined function in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

How to show Quick Help for the methods which we wrote ...?
Like for inbuilt function when we right click on it & Click Quick Help then we get all info about that method like that I want to do for user defined methods so that any one come to know that method takes which parameter and each parameter for which purpose?
For more explanation, see these two images:

[image: THis image shows when click on inbuilt function of UITextField]

[image: THis image shows when click on user defined function of UITextField]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [solution](http://xcodebook.com/2011/04/providing-your-own-quick-help/) for that. Also check [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/Documentation_Sets/000-Introduction/introduction.html). You might have to create document set and install it in Xcode.

**Edit:** Here is another similar post, [How do you populate the Xcode 4 "Option+Click" popover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751278/how-do-you-populate-the-xcode-4-optionclick-popover)

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source tool called [appledoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/) which helps with this. You can provide your own documentation in the header files and then run the appledoc script which will (depending on your settings) generate the docsets, install them into Xcode, create a HTML for the documentation as well as rss feeds so that changes to the documentation can be published.